# javascript, forEach and removeChild unpredictable behavior

Tags: javascript, removechild

I wish to remove all items from a list and replace them with others

```
var list = document.querySelector("ul");
[].forEach.call(list.childNodes, list.removeChild.bind(list));
```

The code above does not work as expected, instead it removes only half the items (leaving every second item in the list).
If i change it to

```
var list = document.querySelector("ul");
[].slice.call(list.childNodes).forEach(list.removeChild.bind(list));
```

Then it works as expected,
can anyone explain ?

Comment: `[].split.call(list.childNodes)` execution raises  `Uncaught TypeError`

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko he obviously meant `[].slice.call(list.childNodes)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Concept

To explain the "unpredictable" behavior in the first scenario, consider this case:

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
```

This makes the behavior easier to explain without the distracting `.call()` and `.bind()` methods to wrap your head around.

```
array.forEach(function(num, index) {
  console.log(num, index);
  array.splice(index, 1);
});
```

You may be wondering why the output is:

```
0 0
2 1
4 2
6 3
```

But it's actually really simple. `.forEach()` iterates over the indices until `i < array.length` is no longer satisfied, while at the beginning of each iteration, your array looks like this:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
 ^
 0

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    ^
    1

[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
       ^
       2

[1, 3, 5, 6, 7];
          ^
          3

[1, 3, 5, 7];
             ^
            (4 < array.length) !== true
```

This is what happens when you manipulate an array being iterated over within a call to `.forEach()`.

For the case where you execute `[].slice.call(array)`, all you're doing is making a shallow copy of all the indices of the array. This allows you to iterate over the *copy's* indices while removing the nodes from the *original*.

Below is a comprehensive example, but make sure your browser supports ES6 template strings.

### Demo

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

document.write(`<p>original.forEach()</p>`);

array.forEach(function(num, index) {
  document.write(`<pre>num: ${num}, index: ${index}, array: [${array}]</pre>`);
  array.splice(index, 1);
});

document.write(`<pre>result: [${array}]</pre>`);

array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

var copy = array.slice();

document.write(`<p>copy.forEach()</p>`);

copy.forEach(function(num, index) {
  document.write(`<pre>num: ${num}, index: ${index}, array: [${array}]</pre>`);
  array.splice(array.indexOf(num), 1); // removing by reference, not by index
});

document.write(`<pre>result: [${array}]</pre>`);
```

```css
body > * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: @MichaelB not that I'm complaining, but why did you unselect this as the best answer?

Comment: Your answer explains the problem better, but for me the consequences of manipulating an array while iterating over it are clear, i just did not understand this was what i am doing, and since the other answer came first i thought the fairest this is to select the first answer that solved my problem.

But i changed my mind, since the question is regarding iterating and manipulating the array, your answer explained it better.

Comment: @MichaelB just to clarify, I was not requesting that you change it back, but I do appreciate you telling me why. That's perfectly acceptable, I was just curious was all.

Answer (score 2):

In the first one you are mutating an array you are iterating over.

In the second you are making a copy and then iterating over it.

The following is another option that doesn't require making a copy:

```
for(; list.firstChild; list.removeChild(list.firstChild));
```

This removes the `firstChild` while it is not `null`.

Comment: Or `while (list.firstChild) list.removeChild(list.firstChild)`, which is more semantic to me. But probably faster is `list.parentNode.replaceChild(list.cloneNode(false), list)`.

Comment: @RobG woo, one byte saved.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts—I don't care about the bytes, I think it's clearer.